# Linearly independent sets of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Find $3$ vectors $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that {$a$, $b$}, {$a$, $c$} and {$b$, $c$} are each linearly independent sets of vectors, but the set {$a$, $b$, $c$} is linearly dependent.

Is there a better way of finding a solution to this problem than just "guessing and check"?

Comment: Look for easy dependences.  Suppose any two of your vectors spans the usual $xy$ plane.

Answer (score 2):

How about taking $a,b$ to be any two linearly independent vectors, and then let $c=a+b$.